# Little Lwt Port Scanner Not Working

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a small Lwt (and batteries) port scanner to better
understand Lwt however I'm getting a strange exception whenever I try to scan
too many ports at a time with scan_ports_range. I'm suspecting my mechanism
for keeping a maximum number of connections open is not working...

`Exception: Unix.Unix_error (Batteries.Unix.EMFILE, "socket","").
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("/home/(censored)/.opam/4.00.1/lib/utop: Too many open files")`

(Which also crashes utop btw)

Code is below. To trigger the error evaluate:
`scan_ports_range ~host:"127.0.0.1" (1000,2000)`

Any critique/suggestions for my lwt style is also welcome since I've
only started learning it.

```
open Lwt

let addr_parts addr = 
  let (host, port) = String.split addr ":" in (host, int_of_string port)

let addr ~host ~port = 
  lwt entry = Lwt_unix.gethostbyname host in
  if Array.length entry.Unix.h_addr_list = 0 then begin
    failwith (Printf.sprintf "no address found for host %S\n" host)
  end;
  return (Unix.ADDR_INET (entry.Unix.h_addr_list.(0), port))

let test_connection ?(timeout=1.0) addr = 
  let fd = Lwt_unix.socket Unix.PF_INET Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0 in
  let connect_close = 
    (Lwt_unix.connect fd addr) >>= (fun () -> Lwt_unix.close fd)  in
  try_lwt
    (pick [connect_close ; Lwt_unix.timeout timeout])
    >>= (fun () -> return true)
  with _ -> return false

let scan_ports ~host ~ports =
  ports |> Lwt_list.map_p (fun port ->
        lwt adr = addr ~host ~port in
        test_connection adr >>= (fun res -> return (res,port)) )
    >>= (fun l -> return ( l |> List.filter_map ( function
      | false, _ -> None | true, port -> Some(port) ) ) )

let scan_ports_range ?(max_open=20) ~host (a, b) =
  let rec loop acc enum = 
    match Enum.peek enum with
    | None -> acc |> List.concat |> List.rev |> return
    | Some _ -> 
        let ports = enum |> Enum.take max_open |> List.of_enum in
        let open_ports = scan_ports ~host ~ports in
        open_ports >>= (fun l -> loop (l::acc) enum )
  in loop [] (a--b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a wild guess, I think you need to force the closing of the socket in case of timeout, so the cullprint might be:

```
pick [connect_close ; Lwt_unix.timeout timeout]
```

Comment: You are right. I had to close the file descriptor in case of the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected code according to Thomas.

```
let test_connection ?(timeout=1.0) addr = 
  let fd = Lwt_unix.socket Unix.PF_INET Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0 in
  let connect_close = 
    (Lwt_unix.connect fd addr) >>= (fun () -> Lwt_unix.close fd)  in
  try_lwt
    (pick [connect_close ; Lwt_unix.timeout timeout])
    >>= (fun () -> return true)
  with _ -> (Lwt_unix.close fd) >>= (fun () -> return false)
```